# How to find current density given resistor, and voltage, using Ohm's law in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current

I was wondering about how to find current density, given a resistor and an electromotive force.

resistor's data are: resistivity = $\rho$, length = $l$, and cross sectional area = $A$.
resistor = $\rho * \frac{l}{A}$.
electromotive force is equal to Ohm's law, $EMF = R*I$, but I need to use microscopic version of Ohm's law, because I need to find current density. $E = \rho * j$, and therefore current density is equal to $j = \frac{E}{\rho}$, I have a question:

> is $E$ equal to $EMF$? why? why not?

if they are the same thing, then I can use microscopic version of Ohm's law, I know $EMF = E$, and I know $EMF$. Otherwise I don't know what to do in order to find $E$.

Comment: Electromotive force comes from a battery or a voltage source. If you connect your resistor to the battery it will be responsible for a current flow an $V_{bat} = I \cdot R = E \cdot l $

Comment: $E = \frac{I*R}{l} = V_(bat)$, right? okay, it was just algebra

Comment: not right V=I*R not I*R/L

Comment: EMF and electric potential (Voltage, V) have the same effect on charges, so they are generally numerically equal.

Comment: in your definition $E l = V$

Answer (score 2):

For current density just use I/A or E=U/L

Comment: what does U stand for?

Comment: @GabrielBurzacchini U is European for potential difference.